# Get value from a tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="?at=privat" at="privat" class="Privat">Privat</a>
```

I need a Jquery to get the privat from above link.
here i Tried .

```
$(".Privat").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


     alert($(this).val());
});
```

but it didn't returns any value?
how can i get the value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `<a>` tag creates an anchor, which doesn't have a value (generally only tags that create inputs do). If you want the value of one of its attributes, then you can use the `.attr()` function.

For example:

```
alert($(this).attr('at')); // alerts "privat"
```

If you want the value of its text (the content between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags), you can use the `.text()` function:

```
alert($(this).text()); // alerts "Privat"
```

If your HTML was a bit different, and your `<a>` tag contained other HTML, rather than just text, like this:

```
<a href="?at=privat" at="privat" class="Privat"><span>Privat</span></a>
```

Then you could use the `.html()` function to do that (it would return `<span>Privat</span>`). The `.text()` would still just return "Privat" even though it's wrapped in a span.

Answer (score 2):

The [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. Try this for getting the link text:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RZSUu/)

Answer (score 2):

to get the value of an attribute use the appropriate function :

```
$(this).attr('at');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
   alert($(this).attr('at'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have privat in many places, but you probably want `$(this).html()` which returns the content of the tag.