# Target the value of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I target the value of the a tag in es6? I don't want to use jQuery

```
function targetEvent(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.);
}

<a href="#">test</a>
```

I want to target this "test" word.

Comment: `textContent` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from a tag in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647941/get-value-from-a-tag-in-jquery)

Comment: It's pretty unclear what your asking here. If you want to read `test` from that `a` tag you can use: `$('a').first().text();`

Comment: what do you mean "target" it? Do you just mean get its value? If so then see Liam's comment above. If not, you'll have to explain what you mean a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach the function to the click event of the element. Then try

```
currentTarget.textContent
```

```js
function targetEvent(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="targetEvent(event)">test</a>
```

**OR:** Using jQuery

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The target event property returns the element that triggered the event.

please try this code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="targetEvent(event)">test</a>

<script>
function targetEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.text);
}
</script>
```

The target property gets the element on which the event originally occurred, opposed to the currentTarget property, which always refers to the element whose event listener triggered the event.

1) to get the text for any tag :

> e.target.text

2) to get the tag name :

> e.target.tagName;

Answer (score 1):

here, I have show simple example to show event target's value.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="test">test</a>
```

JS

```
let test = document.getElementById('test');
test.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   console.log(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your target element is.

For an input type of element, you would use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), but for an anchor tag, like in your example, assuming you want to extract the "test" text, you would use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

If you want the entire HTML content of the element, you can even use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

You'll see that for certain elements, the output of these functions are similar.

Don't forget that in order to use these functions, you need to ensure that [the element you are working with is a query object](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```js
function targetEvent(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(e.target)
  console.log(".text()", target.text())
  console.log(".html()", target.html())
  console.log(".val()", target.val())
}

$(function(){
  $('.clickMe').on('click', targetEvent)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="clickMe" href="#">test</a>
<h3 class="clickMe"><span>inner content</span></h3>
<textarea class="clickMe">Some text</textarea>
```